# previous definition of 'class mpicomm' error

Tags: c++

Could someone tell me why am I getting this error?

"previous definition of 'class mpicomm'"

```
class mpicomm{

public:
    mpicomm()
    {

    }
};
```

thanks!

Comment: In the lines that the compiler has processed before the lines you have shown us there is a definition of `class mpicomm`.  You're welcome !

Comment: You didn't use include guards.

Comment: This could happen when you include header file contain this definition twice. Better give us more details on file `.h` and `.cpp` contents and exact compiler error

Comment: the compiler just says "mpi_comm.h:1: error: redefinition of 'class mpicomm" and  "error: previous definition of 'class mpicomm'". I tried to change the name of the class but the error doens't  disappear.

Answer (score 3):

A class can be defined only once per translation unit, and has to have the same definition across translation units.

This error is typically caused by including the header that defines the class multiple times (directly or indirectly) and should be fixed by using include guards.

Comment: `#if !defined(HAS_UPVOTED_ANSWER) #define HAS_UPVOTED_ANSWER #endif`